# systemd update conflicts with upstart

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, systemd, upstart

On my Ubuntu Server 18.04 (originally installed as 14.04 and upgraded to 18.04 few months ago), systemd update has now been "kept back".

I looked at it in aptitude and it says that dependencies are not satisfied:

- systemd(upgrade, 237-3ubuntu10.29 -> 237-3ubuntu10.31) conflicts with upstart

I know Ubuntu used to use upstart but have no idea if my installation still uses it or if it's safe to remove it. It's a production server. I can have down time only during weekend. I would very much like to avoid breaking it by messing with the boot process.

What should I do and how?

Comment: Upstart was last used in 16.04. During the upgrade from 14.04 to 18.04 it probably didn't get removed. Wait for a few more experts to chime in, but you can probably remove upstart. Do a good backup first.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation (although I'm not sure if my machine first had 14.04 or 12.04 installed!) I'm thinking that the only real solution is to back everything up, try the update, and, if it ruins the system, just reinstall the latest LTS from scratch. The further we go, the more Linux just becomes Windows.

Comment: @tsbertalan Hi, I've had time to do the update yesterday. I simply removed the upstart (after checking that it is not being used for init) and that solved it - no issues. But yeah, be sure to backup first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to simply remove package upstart.

If you encounter same situation, be sure to do following before removing upstart:

1. check that upstart isn't actually used (you can check name of executable for init process)
2. backup your system